# FIWARE Orion, NGSIv2 subscription in attributes with structured values

Tags: fiware, fiware-orion

I'm working with Orion Contex Broker and I need to receive notifications when a parameter in a structured attribute changes its value. An example:

1. **Subscription**:

```
curl -iX POST \
--url 'http://localhost:1026/v2/subscriptions' \
--header 'content-type: application/json' \
--data '{
   "description":"Notify me of Store changes in street Address",
   "subject":{
      "entities":[
     {
        "idPattern":".*",
        "type":"Store"
     }
      ],
      "condition":{
     "attrs":[
        "address.streetAddress"
     ]
      }
   },
   "notification":{
      "http":{
     "url":"http://localhost:3000/subscription/store-change"
      }
   }
}'
```

2. **Create entity**:

```
curl -iX POST \
--url 'http://localhost:1026/v2/op/update' \
-H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
-d '{
   "actionType":"append",
   "entities":[
      {
         "type":"Store",
         "id":"urn:ngsi-ld:Store:001",
         "address":{
            "type":"PostalAddress",
            "value":{
               "streetAddress":"Old",
               "addressRegion":"Berlin"
            }
         },
         "name":{
            "type":"Text",
            "value":"Bösebrücke Einkauf"
         }
      }
   ]
}'
```

3. **Update the entity**:

```
curl -iX PATCH \
--url 'http://localhost:1026/v2/entities/urn:ngsi-ld:Store:001/attrs' \
-H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
-d '{
   "address":{
      "type":"PostalAddress",
      "value":{
         "streetAddress":"Bornholmer"
      }
   }
}'
```

The expected result would be to receive a notification when the entity was created and update. Another possibility could be the "condition expressions". However one of kind: `"q": "address.streetAddress!=${previousValue}"` is not implemented yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Attributes within NGSI are usually numbers or strings - this typically leads to a very flat data model. In this case when the attribute value changes the subscription would be fired.

JSON objects (such as `address` above) are also supported, but the change occurs whenever the Object's `value` change and is not specifically bound to a sub attribute Hence

```
"attrs":[
   "address.streetAddress"
]
```

Would need to be:

```
"attrs":[
   "address"
]
```

However, the `q` parameter could be used to filter against a specific sub-attribute e.g. `q=address.streetAddress!="Old"` - and the listening interface could amend the subscription after it has fired.